# Phone is recongized in Ubuntu but cannot be found in dev/sdb

Tags: usb, mount, android

I have a LG v10 and when I plug it into Ubuntu 12.02, it is recognized and Ubuntu says it's mounted but when I run `ls /dev/sd*`, it's not listed. It is found under `lsusb` but I need the device name. I also can't view any files on the device, I get the error:

> Sorry, could not display all the contents of "LGE Android Phone": DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

I've tried several USB cables but they all give the same result. also, my end goal here is to work on a bricked G4 so using adb or anything like that isn't going to help, I need to be able to see the device in `/dev/sd*`

After waiting for a while I can view the files on the phone but it's still not detected under `/dev/sd*`

Running `gdisk -l /dev/bus/usb/xxx/xxx` for the phones bus and ID returns an error stating that the device is a character device

Any thoughts?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 12.02 and if this is an Android device with Android version 4 or later you'll need to use to at least 14.04 for mtp working plug and play.

Comment: And mtp won't make the phone come up as a block device instead of a character device anyway: it's a feature of the Phone's BIOS/firmware/OS

Comment: Shouldn't it show up as a block device capable of storage though?

Comment: Essentially, how can I access the partitions of the phones storage? It's not listed as a device so applications like gparted don't pick it up and I can't go through adb or anything that requires android, I need to access the filesystem directly. Originally I was following this guide, which seems to work for others, but I don't know how to get the phone to come up as a device http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2582142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether a device (phone in your case) comes up as a block device (`/dev/XdY` where `X` and `Y` are hardware-dependent) or a character device (`/run/user/nnnn/gvfs/mtp:`) are a feature of the combined device's hardware and OS.

So you'll never be able to have it listed as a block device (unless you write your own kernel module).

Having said that: you can always physically remove the memory from the device, solder it on a USB stick's controller hardware, plug it into your machine and access it as a block device that way, but that is more a solution fit for [Lifehacks](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com) then [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

***Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.***

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: [lifehacks.se]? I'd consider it more appropriate for [electronics.se], don't you?